# Two audio channels for two voices for AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: swift, avaudiosession, avspeechsynthesizer

Using iOS-10.12.2, Swift-3.0.2, Xcode-8.2.1,

I am trying to let two voices speak simultaneously using the AVSpeechSynthesizer.

In fact, there are two texts as a basis and the two voices shall synthesize these two texts simultaneously with two different voices (same language).

Doing so for one voice is simple (see code below).

But how do I set up two audio-channels for the two voices ?

Is my wish doable at all using AVSpeechSynthesizer ?

Here is a code-excert for doing text-to-speech for once text and one voice:

```
// ...
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
// var channelNames = [AVAudioSessionChannelDescription]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func textToSpeachButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    self.myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: textView.text)
    self.myUtterance.rate = 0.4
    self.myUtterance.volume = 1.0

    self.speakWithVoiceOfPerson(person: "Anna")

}

func speakWithVoiceOfPerson(person: String) {
    for voice in AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() {
        print(voice.name)
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            if voice.name == person {
                self.myUtterance.voice = voice
            }
        }
    }
    synth.speak(self.myUtterance)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to let two voices speak simultaneously using the AVSpeechSynthesizer.

It's definitely not possible in iOS 12, **only one speech synthesis is vocally processed at a time**.

However, you can play [an audio session](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18236.html#Basics) together with the speech synthesis.

Comment: I did not have time to test this yet (lower priority)

Comment: @iKK: no need to test anything, that's the solution provided by Apple itself.  ;o)